# running the application under local system in a user session

Tags: windows, go, winapi, windows-services

I have an application, it is written in the Go language, it works as a windows service, the service is run on behalf of the system. This application runs ffmpeg so that ffmpeg can capture the screen I run it in a user session.
I use a user token to launch it. I get the token using WinAPI WTSQueryUserToken + DuplicateTokenEx. Is it possible to run ffmpeg under a local system account, but in a user session?

code

```golang
token, err := wintoken.GetInteractiveToken(wintoken.TokenLinked) // use "github.com/fourcorelabs/wintoken"
//.....

a.cmd.SysProcAttr = &syscall.SysProcAttr{
        Token:         syscall.Token(token.Token()),
        CreationFlags: 0x08000000,
    }
```

this example works, but when running in a session without admin rights, I get an error when trying to get a token
"A specified logon session does not exist. It may already have been terminated."
I thought maybe running under localsystem would solve the problem

Comment: of course possible run as local system. simply duplicate self current token, set in it session id and use

Comment: i can set the session ID token using? 
settokeninformation + _TOKEN_INFORMATION_CLASS = TokenSessionId

Comment: yes, you can set session id in token (first need duplicate existing) you need TOKEN_ADJUST_SESSIONID|TOKEN_ADJUST_DEFAULT for TokenSessionId